# How to darken flagstone edge on fireplace hearth

Tags: fireplace, sealer

What can I use to color/darken the edge of a flagstone hearth. House built 1967. Hearth appears to have an unknown sealer on it - slight sheen, very water resistant. Top has nice color variation but edges are a much lighter mostly solid color. Stripping and heavy sanding is not really an option.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. A picture would help, but I'm guessing this will be closed as a product request and/or decorating question. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I agree if normal elbow grease or stripping in not an option it is a request for a product VTC.

Answer (score 1):

You darken flagstone with sealer/color-additive.   Or you can try heat.  I have darkened flagstone outside using a blowtorch, it works.   I am not suggesting that you do this as the results will vary and the sealer may melt weird or possibly start a "small fire".   The method does work as I have used it for outdoor grills and fire pits but saying that I would not have practiced my first time inside.

There is no quick fix for this.   You have to get sealer off first no matter what.   Even with past experience no way I am torching something with sealant on it.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to strip the sealer off, then you will need to use something that sticks to the sealer rather than absorbing into the stone. Paint is a possibility.

Comment: paint over sealer and stone - minus...

Comment: @DMoore, if you have a better idea for the OP who says stripping and sanding is not an option, please provide it.